# Spider and fly problem

Tags: puzzle, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry

I am a novice in computational geometry and I would like to address some questions about the spider - fly problem as stated in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_spider_and_the_fly_problem

1. I know that there is at least a shortest arc on the cuboid, connecting the point "fly" and the point "spider" but I do not know why this is called **geodesic**? **Geodesic is locally a shortsest arc but not via versa...**
2. In order to find a shortest arc (according to wiki), we have to:

   a. Check in all the 11 possible nets (edge unfolding, without overlapping) of the cuboid if the line segment "fly""spider" belongs to the corresponding net.

   b. Compare the lengths of these line segments (at most 11) and choose the shortest. This is a shortest arc. But why to check only the **edge**, not overlapping unfoldings and not all  the possible **general**, not overlapping unfoldings? Maybe there is a shortest arc also there...

Thanks.

**EDIT**

When I say general unfolding, I mean such as: Star Unfolding, Source Unfolding, Aleksandrov Unfolding, etc

Comment: @user2661923,  I mean exactly what is writen in  your last comment. Thanks.

Comment: As I understand it, you are first considering all paths discoverable by all of the ways of unfolding along the edges.  Then, you are wondering whether there is some hidden shorter path that also involves unfolding along something other than the edges.  I have tried **and failed** to construct a rigorous proof that any such path (or a pertinent shorter path) would also be discoverable by only unfolding along the edges.  Since I have failed, I have upvoted your question, in the hope that someone else may give a rigorous answer.

Comment: I think I have an idea taken from your comments.  It is not about finding all edge unfoldings.... It is about taking all possible edge roots that lead from spider to fly.  Every such root creates an edge unfolding.  Also in such unfolding the line segment of 2 points lie inside the net,  (maybe bcs are chosen carefully so....), @user2661923

Comment: If you think that you have a rigorous proof, then I suggest that you post it as a separate answer.  If so, please address a comment to me, I would like to read your answer.  The problem that I had was in trying to anticipate all of the possible paths *discoverable* by also allowing *other* unfoldings.  I was unable to conclusively prove that a pertinent [not-longer] path would be discoverable by only considering edge unfoldings.  ...see next comment

Comment: The only approach that I could see was to assume that point A was on face-1, and that point C was on one of the other 5 faces, and divide the examination into 5 cases.  I am simply too lazy to descend into such a brute force examination.  Note, that you also have to consider that the dimensions of the cuboid are variable, which may or may not complicate whatever approach that you take.

Comment: For what it's worth, I first assumed that there was exactly one edge crossing in the discovered path, and then that there were exactly two edge crossings in the discovered paths, where discovery included non-edge unfoldings.  The problem that I had was in trying to construct a rigorous argument that would apply if there were exactly $(n)$ edge crossings in the path discovered by using non-edge unfoldings.

Comment: @user2661923, I made an answer....I hope this is what you meant....in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

According to user 2661923  helpfull comments, it suffices to examine all the possible "edge paths" that lead spider "A" to fly point "B". So the possible paths are:

1. A-left wall-floor-B
2. A-left wall-B
3. A-left wall-ceiling-B
4. A-floor-B
5. A-floor-left wall-B
6. A-floor-left wall-ceiling-B
7. A-celling-B
8. A-ceilling-left wall-B
9. A-ceilling-left wall-floor-B

Notice we do not have to examine right wall, bcs of symmetry and of course not to take the same edge again as it would make the path greater.

According to each of these edge paths we can produce an edge unfolding of the cuboid.

Now because in the above 9 considerations the segment  $AB$ **lie inside the appropriate planar net** (I made some paper modeling and found it out) we can easily find the distance accordingly. This is not always the case if we have a general cuboid....

Comment: This problem fried my brain.  Better to let someone else, with a fresh outlook, evaluate your answer.